# How can I ping all address is subnet in Windows for IPv6

Tags: windows, ipv6

How can I go about programmatically pinging all address through Windows for an IPv6 network.

My address is fe80::1881:1fc2:a153:71f0%3(Preferred).

I have done this via IPv4 with no issue, but having a hard time understanding how to do this to build my ARP table for IPv6.

Comment: There is no ARP table in IPv6. And this question is a pretty blatant [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912). What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I go about programmatically [sic] pinging all address through
> Windows for an IPv6 network. [sic]

If you try to ping every one of the possible `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` addresses on a standard `/64` IPv6 network, at `1,000,000` addresses per second, it will take you over `584,542` years. You simply cannot try to ping every host on an IPv6 network.

> ...having a hard time understanding how to do this to build my ARP table
> for IPv6.

IPv6 doesn't use ARP. IPv6 uses ND. IPv6 ND maintains a few tables, among them are the Neighbor Cache and the Destination Cache.

[RFC 4861, Neighbor Discovery for IP version 6 (IPv6)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861), explains the host data structures for IPv6 ND.

> 5.1.  Conceptual Data Structures
>
> Hosts will need to maintain the following pieces of information for
> each interface:
>
> Neighbor Cache
>
> - A set of entries about individual neighbors to which traffic has been    sent recently.  Entries are keyed on the neighbor's on-link
>   unicast    IP address and contain such information as its link-layer
>   address, a    flag indicating whether the neighbor is a router or a
>   host (called    IsRouter in this document), a pointer to any queued
>   packets waiting    for address resolution to complete, etc.  A
>   Neighbor Cache entry also    contains information used by the Neighbor
>   Unreachability Detection    algorithm, including the reachability
>   state, the number of unanswered    probes, and the time the next
>   Neighbor Unreachability Detection event    is scheduled to take place.
>
> Destination Cache
>
> - A set of entries about destinations to which
>   traffic has been sent recently.  The Destination
>   Cache includes both on-link and off-link
>   destinations and provides a level of indirection
>   into the Neighbor Cache; the Destination Cache maps
>   a destination IP address to the IP address of the
>   next-hop neighbor.  This cache is updated with
>   information learned from Redirect messages.
>   Implementations may find it convenient to store
>   additional information not directly related to
>   Neighbor Discovery in Destination Cache entries,
>   such as the Path MTU (PMTU) and round-trip timers
>   maintained by transport protocols.
>
> Prefix List
>
> - A list of the prefixes that define a set of
>   addresses that are on-link.  Prefix List entries
>   are created from information received in Router
>   Advertisements.  Each entry has an associated
>   invalidation timer value (extracted from the
>   advertisement) used to expire prefixes when they
>   become invalid.  A special "infinity" timer value
>   specifies that a prefix remains valid forever,
>   unless a new (finite) value is received in a
>   subsequent advertisement.   The link-local prefix is considered to be on the
>   prefix list with an infinite invalidation timer
>   regardless of whether routers are advertising a
>   prefix for it.  Received Router Advertisements
>   SHOULD NOT modify the invalidation timer for the
>   link-local prefix.
>
> Default Router List
>
> - A list of routers to which packets may be sent.
>   Router list entries point to entries in the
>   Neighbor Cache; the algorithm for selecting a
>   default router favors routers known to be reachable
>   over those whose reachability is suspect.  Each
>   entry also has an associated invalidation timer
>   value (extracted from Router Advertisements) used
>   to delete entries that are no longer advertised.